# Serverless Solution for Google Drive watch changes

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-drive-api, google-cloud-functions, serverless

I'd like to make a firebase function that is triggered by the Google Drive "Changes: watch":

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/changes/watch

I know I could probably do this with Google cloud storage, but for my use case it would be the best UX for my users to have Google drive watch for and upload file changes.

I'd like this to be a serverless solution to save money on running a server that is waiting/polling all the time. Ideally this can be done in firebase functions with a trigger as I'm parsing the data into Firestore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Google Drive Push Notifications API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/push).

Setup your WebHook to point to your firebase function endpoint:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/changes/watch
Authorization: Bearer auth_token_for_current_user
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "id": "4ba78bf0-6a47-11e2-bcfd-0800200c9a77", // Your channel ID.
  "type": "web_hook",
  "address": "<your-function-endpoint>", // Your receiving URL.
  "token": "target=myApp-myChangesChannelDest", // (Optional) Your channel token.
}
```